# Running Fitnesse or Selenium tests in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, fitnesse

Is there a way to run Fitnesse or Selenium GUI web (example to open a website in a browser) tests from a Jenkins job without installing a browser on the Jenkins server ?

I am completely new to automation testing . Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can run selenium test using [headless browser](https://blog.avenuecode.com/how-to-build-headless-browser-testing-and-integrate-with-jenkins). This is the easiest way to execute test without opening browsers GUI.

Comment: If I use a headless browser with Chrome Driver , then in that case I don't need to install Chrome Browser on the Jenkins Server ?

Comment: No, you don't have to install any browser. Refer to the post I have mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: @souravatta a headless chrome still needs chrome (and chromedriver) to be present on the server. In your blog I see nothing that suggests otherwise (other than that you assume it is present) and you even mention that the chromedriver must be downloaded and installed.

Comment: Can you use docker on your Jenkins machine? (In that case you can use a docker image with a browser instead of installing it on the Jenkins machine itself).
Are you an administrator on some other machine the Jenkins server can connect to? (In that case the Jenkins jobs can be configured to use a browser installed on that machine)

Comment: Chrome driver is necessary and yes it needs to be present to use it for headless mode. But the fact here is not to open browser GUI, that is why headless mode.

Comment: I tried using Chrome Driver in headless mode . The exception that I got was : org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary . It seems to be the case that it is also searching for a Chrome Binary Distribution (eg. chrome.exe)

Comment: @fried hoeben : can I set path to chrome binary if it is not present at default location in Fitnesse ?

Comment: Did you end up installing chrome and the driver? In that case it seems this question should be closed. Configuring selenium/chrome is best as separate question (don't forget to mention how you use selenium from fitnesse)

Comment: I have copied the binary to my workspace in Jenkins and also the chrome driver . But the while running the Fitnesse tests in Jenkins it's still not able to locate the chrome binary . I need a way to tell Fitnesse to check chrome binary in a different location . This question can be closed . I can conclude that definitely we need chrome installation on Jenkins to run Browser tests.